# Spring: request method is modified before getting to DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httprequest

My web application based on Spring MVC has a problem. When I'm submitting form with method POST, the controller sometimes executes method GET. It happens completely randomly. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes not.
It is running on jboss soa p 5 an using spring framework 3.1.4 (previously was 3.0.1)

In front-end i'm submitting from by simply performing:

```
document.submitform.submit();
```

when I'm logging request method in javascript before form submission, it is always POST. But after analyzing springframework debug log, I see that it receives GET method:

```
2014-08-11 11:33:52,894 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ajp-172.31.14.7-8109-9) DispatcherServlet with name 'Flow' processing GET request for [/project/mypage/mypage.htm]
2014-08-11 11:33:52,894 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] (ajp-172.31.14.7-8109-9) Looking up handler method for path /mypage/mypage.htm
2014-08-11 11:33:52,894 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (ajp-172.31.14.7-8109-9) Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'myController'
2014-08-11 11:33:52,894 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ajp-172.31.14.7-8109-9) Last-Modified value for [/project/mypage/mypage.htm] is: -1
```

**So this is my problem**: when the request is sent, the method in the front-end side is ok, but in DispatcherServlet is modified, but request URI is ok. And it is happening completely randomly. What could be the reason of it?
As I understand there are another classes where request method could be modified before DispatcherServlet. How can I see which request method I have in ResponseOverrideFilter or in RequestContextListener or in DelegatingFilterProxy? (debug for org.springframework doesn't provide this information. only for DispatcherServlet)

I've updated spring version from 3.0 to 3.1, but it didn't solve my problem.

*Edit1*:
After performing request Apache access.log says `IP - - [11/Aug/2014:13:00:18 +0100] "GET /project/mypage/mypage.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 31489`. so as was mentioned in comments, the problem is on the front-end side.

Comment: Do you have any HTTP server in front of JBoss? May be Apache?

Comment: yes, it is Apache and in cluster mode

Comment: Do you always see a GET soon after a POST? If you do, perhaps the client is doing a GET after the POST. If so, the problem (such as it is) is on the client side.

Comment: So, let's try to examine how are you submitting your form. I believe that this is not static HTML form with submit button pressed by user but some dynamic content written in Javascript. Am I right?

Comment: @viktorovich, you can also check what your browser is thinking about your requests. Use developer tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox, select "network" tab to see the requests. Check whether all your requests use POST or not. Alternatively you can use WireShark to see your network traffic.

Comment: @AlexR in wireshark I also see Get requests, so it is definitively fornt-end problem. Must to be something wrong in js... now it is another problem. Thank you for help, because I was not sure on which side the problem was.

Comment: @viktorovich, NP, good luck with your investigation. And ... I like the landscape behind you on your profile picture...